# How can I typeset a command and its literal equivalent in an environment?

Tags: environments, documentation, environment-variables

*UPDATE: I've opened a follow-up question: [How can I typeset an environment and its literal equivalent in an environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240317/how-can-i-typeset-an-environment-and-its-literal-equivalent-in-an-environment)*

---

I would like to pass a command and arguments to an environment. The output should be threefold:

1. The literal command
2. The typeset version (how it should appear when used)
3. The definition of the command. (This is just a textual description of what the command is used for.)

## My Attempt

For this example, I try to use the `\key` command provided by the [`menukeys` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys?lang=en).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\NewEnviron{command}[1]{% 
\par
\reversemarginpar\marginnote{\texttt{\string#1}}
\BODY
\par
\textbf{Example:} % And here is #1 with #2, but literally typeset (e.g. literally \keys{Shift + F5})
\par
%#1#2 % <-- I'd like to typeset these two inputs properly (e.g. non-literal \keys{Shift + F5})
\par
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{command}{\keys}% {{Shift + F5}} % Example input does not work
This command allows you to add keyboard strokes. % here is the definition followed by an example on the next line.
\end{command}

\end{document}
```

## Desired Output

[image]

## My Thoughts

Maybe this is not even the right approach. I do not know how to go about dealing the commands with multiple arguments efficiently (e.g. created with the `xparse` package).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should absorb the two arguments verbatim, which `xparse` allows to do; then you can “rescan” the two arguments when you want to show the effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{command}{vv}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_macmad_argument_i_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_macmad_argument_ii_tl { #2 }
  \par
  \noindent
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\ttfamily\l_macmad_argument_i_tl\hspace{2em}}
  \ignorespaces
 }
 {
  \par\nopagebreak
  \noindent
  \textbf{Example:~}
  \texttt
   {
    \l_macmad_argument_i_tl
    \tl_if_blank:VF \l_macmad_argument_ii_tl
     { \{ \l_macmad_argument_ii_tl \} }
   }
  \\*
  \tl_set_rescan:NnV \l_macmad_argument_tl {} \l_macmad_argument_i_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VF \l_macmad_argument_ii_tl
   {
    \tl_set_rescan:NnV \l_macmad_temp_tl {} \l_macmad_argument_ii_tl
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_macmad_argument_tl { { \exp_not:V \l_macmad_temp_tl } }
   }
  \l_macmad_argument_tl
  \par
 }
\tl_new:N \l_macmad_argument_tl
\tl_new:N \l_macmad_argument_i_tl
\tl_new:N \l_macmad_argument_ii_tl
\tl_new:N \l_macmad_temp_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set_rescan:Nnn { NnV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{command}{\keys}{Shift + F5}
This command allows you to add keyboard strokes.
\end{command}

\begin{command}{\TeX}{}
This command prints the \TeX\ logo.
\end{command}

\begin{command}{\textbf}{\TeX}
This command prints its argument in bold.
\end{command}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can accommodate more than one argument, but in this case you need to use braces for the mandatory ones, even if there's only one of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage{xparse} % but it's already loaded by fontspec

\ExplSyntaxOn
% "v" means "verbatim argument"
\NewDocumentEnvironment{command}{vv}
 {
  % store the two arguments in variables
  % xparse has absorbed them "verbatim"
  \tl_set:Nn \l_macmad_argument_i_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_macmad_argument_ii_tl { #2 }
  \par
  \noindent
  % print the first argument in the margin
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\ttfamily\l_macmad_argument_i_tl\hspace{2em}}
  \ignorespaces
 }
 {
  \par\nopagebreak
  \noindent
  \textbf{Example:~}
  \texttt
   {
    % print the first argument
    \l_macmad_argument_i_tl
    % print the second argument (but only if non empty)
    \tl_if_blank:VF \l_macmad_argument_ii_tl
     { \l_macmad_argument_ii_tl }
   }
  \\*
  % transform back the first argument from verbatim into "standard tokens"
  \tl_set_rescan:NnV \l_macmad_argument_tl {} \l_macmad_argument_i_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VF \l_macmad_argument_ii_tl
   {
    % do the same for the second argument (if non empty)
    \tl_set_rescan:NnV \l_macmad_temp_tl {} \l_macmad_argument_ii_tl
    % append the rescanned text to the previous
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_macmad_argument_tl { \exp_not:V \l_macmad_temp_tl }
   }
  % process the contents of the rescanned arguments
  \l_macmad_argument_tl
  \par
 }

% allocate the variables
\tl_new:N \l_macmad_argument_tl
\tl_new:N \l_macmad_argument_i_tl
\tl_new:N \l_macmad_argument_ii_tl
\tl_new:N \l_macmad_temp_tl
% generate a variant command
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set_rescan:Nnn { NnV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{command}{\keys}{{Shift + F5}}
This command allows you to add keyboard strokes.
\end{command}

\begin{command}{\TeX}{}
This command prints the \TeX\ logo.
\end{command}

\begin{command}{\textbf}{{\TeX}}
This command prints its argument in bold.
\end{command}

\begin{command}{\framebox}{[3cm][l]{\TeX}}
This command frames text in a specified area.
\end{command}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This method currently doesn't allow commands with multiple arguments, although I'm sure that could be fixed.

Comment: @JonasGranholm Yes, but the syntax changes a bit: you need to supply the braces around a single mandatory argument. Not a big deal, as you gain the possibility of expressing whatever combination of arguments.

Comment: @egreg My favorite is the recursive definition: `This command prints the \TeX\ logo.`

Comment: @egreg What is this `\tl_set:Nn` business? I lost control of the code because I don't understand it. As it turns out, I don't want the commands to be in the margin. Normally I would just get rid of the `marginnote` and use a minipage or something. Also, I find it confusing that the first example uses `xparse`, but the second one does not. Really great work! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @macmadness86 I commented the code, do `texdoc interface3` for more information.

Comment: @egreg Ok, I was able to get the literal command into a node like this `\tikz \node [fill=blue!15] {\l_macmad_argument_i_tl};\par`. However, I was not able to do the same to the typeset/reread version `\l_macmad_argument_tl` for some reason. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I am sitting here with a paper copy of the `xparse` documentation in front of me. I will check out `interface3`

Comment: @egreg The interface3 manual states that `tl`=token list and that `l`= parameters whose value should only be set locally. Are those referring to what you have as `\tl` and `\l`? I also see the `_tl` appended to the variable name.

Comment: @macmadness86 Yes, precisely. Moreover, when a variable name is defined, it is good practice to end the name with `_<type>`, so `_tl`, `_seq`, `_clist` and so on.

Comment: @egreg Why is the second `\l_macmad_argument_ii_tl` in `\tl_if_blank:VF \l_macmad_argument_ii_tl {\l_macmad_argument_ii_tl }` in braces?

Comment: @egreg Sorry to be such a nag, but I really want to understand this. In your rescan, you create a new arg `\l_macmad_argument_tl` to contain the standard tokens of arg1 e.g. `\framebox` Then you follow it with `{}` which I don't understand, then `\l_macmad_argument_i_tl`. The manual states that rescan takes "⟨tl var⟩ {⟨setup⟩} {⟨tokens⟩}". tl var=`\l_macmad_argument_tl`, setup=`{}`, tokens=`\l_macmad_argument_i_tl`? Is that correct? Where is your setup? And if it is just `{}`, what does that mean?

Comment: @macmadness86 `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn` requires three arguments: the variable to set, optional assignments (in this case none) and the tokens to rescan. Here I use a variant `\tl_set_rescan:NnV` where the third argument is taken to be the value of a variable.

Answer (score 8):

Is not exactly what you asked, but may be is useful for someone. The advantage is that the [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package can print the LaTeX code and the result of this code in a environment with a lot of options.

> [image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\newtcblisting{command}{sidebyside,width=.55\linewidth,nobeforeafter,baseline=5mm,lefthand ratio=0.65}
\parskip1em
\begin{document}

Print the \TeX\ logo \dotfill \begin{command}\TeX\end{command} 

Add keyboard strokes \dotfill \begin{command}\keys{Shift + F5}\end{command}

Print argument in bold \dotfill \begin{command}\textbf{\TeX}\end{command}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**:

Another rigid but simple solution is the package [example](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/example):

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{menukeys,example,lipsum}
\parindent0in\parskip1em
\begin{document}

This command allows you to add keyboard strokes.%
\begin{example}
\keys{Shift + F5}
\end{example}

This command prints the \TeX\ logo.
\begin{example}
\TeX
\end{example}

This command prints its argument in bold.
\begin{example}
\textbf{\TeX}
\end{example}

This print a boxed dummy text.  

\begin{example}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\raggedright
\tiny\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing another option. My problem with the `tcolorbox` option is that it does not fully support `hyperref`. Perhaps in future versions this will not be the case.

Answer (score 4):

This should do as wanted, and also allows multiple arguments. The only problem is that if there are control sequences in the second argument they are appended with a space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\NewEnviron{command}[2]{% 
\par
\reversemarginpar\marginnote{\texttt{\string#1}}
\BODY
\par
\textbf{Example:}
\texttt{\string#1\detokenize{#2}}
\par
#1#2
\par
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{command}{\keys}{{Shift + F5}}
This command allows you to add keyboard strokes.
\end{command}

\begin{command}{\TeX}{}
This command prints the \TeX\ logo.
\end{command}

\begin{command}{\textbf}{{\TeX}}
This command prints its argument in bold.
\end{command}

\begin{command}{\rule}{[-2pt]{1em}{1em}}
This command print a black box.
\end{command}

\end{document}
```

[image: The output produced by the code]

Comment: You also end up with issues in the event a command takes no arguments.

Comment: Edited to remove that problem :)