# How to write code as normal text?

Tags: code

I got an assignment where i have to explain some code and to do that i have to show my code as normal text. I have no idea how to show my code so is there anyone that could show me how it's done?

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item test.
\item test.
\item test.
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you elaborate your requirement? Like posting screenshot, etc...

Comment: Only the code? Not also the results like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239912/11604) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241910/11604)?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `\verbatim`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test.
\item test.
\item test.
\end{enumerate}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

You can also do it with `\listings`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test.
\item test.
\item test.
\end{enumerate}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```